# Heating fan and weaker battery in Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: lubuntu, battery, fan

Since I switched from Ubuntu to Lubuntu (both 13.04) I spotted some differences:

- Battery life is about 30% shorter. At first I thought that the indicator shows wrong values, so I decided not to charge it till it dies, but it turned off right away!
- The fan is heating constantly for no obvious reason. For instance, CPU is less than 10% (KiB Mem:   6017268 total,  2138152 used,  3879116 free,   118712 buffers)
- There is a huge delay before password prompt appears after "apt-get" - type command

How do I fix these issues?

Of course, those are only the negative ones, Lubuntu works slightly faster and has less default apps.

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: @Vasa1 isn't this a question?!

Comment: @ Alvar, when was the edit made? When was my comment made?

Comment: Please, stick to the subject :)